# ERROR with this combination : mPDF on Yii 1.1.29 + php 7.4

Tags: php, yii, mpdf

Hi I’m trying to migrate my yii app to Php 7.4,

In the process I found that mPDF need to be upgraded.

So I get into “protected” folder, and run “composer intall mpdf/mpdf”, this create a
composer.json file and the vendor folder, with the mpdf lib in there.

then i downloaded this extension " yii-pdf" … and tweak the value in

```
‘librarySourcePath’ => ‘application.vendor.mpdf.mpdf.src.*’,
```

And I have this Error:

```
error exception.ReflectionException
ReflectionException: Class \Mpdf\Mpdf does not exist in
C:\laragon\www\sga_ceia\protected\extensions\yii-pdf\EYiiPdf.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 C:\laragon\www\sga_ceia\protected\extensions\yii-pdf\EYiiPdf.php(82):
 ReflectionClass->__construct(‘\Mpdf\Mpdf’)
#1 C:\laragon\www\sga_ceia\protected\extensions\yii-pdf\EYiiPdf.php(105):
 EYiiPdf->initLibrary(‘mpdf’, Array)
```

Can I use mPDF without yiiPdf ??
How I use the autoloader in that case?

is any other solution??

Best Regards

I have PHP 7.4, Yii 1.1.29

the composer install mPdf 8.2

yiiPdf is 11 years old !

Answer (score 1):

I solved using this

```
// Require composer autoload
require Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendor').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'autoload.php';
// Create an instance of the class:
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

I don't know if there is other way.

I think this mean, I'm not using yiiPdf...